# ChartJS: chartjs-plugin-datalabels not showing value properly

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, chart.js, chart.js-datalabels

I'm attempting to create a chart using Chart.js and I'm using the 4.4.1 version for creating a horizontal chart.

In my code, the data labels are currently displayed as "x: 222, y: 1" but I intend for them to show only the main value, which is "222".

I am using below script tag below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@4.4.1/dist/chart.umd.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
```

Below is my code:

```
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    afterInit: chart => {
      let dataset = chart.data.datasets[0];
      chart.data.datasets = chart.data.labels.map((l, i) => ({
        label: l,
        data: [{ x: dataset.data[i], y: i }],
        backgroundColor: dataset.backgroundColor[i],
        categoryPercentage: 1
      }));
      chart.data.labels = undefined;
    },
    beforeLayout: chart => {
      chart.options.scales.y1.labels = chart.data.datasets.filter((ds, i) => !chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden).map(ds => ds.label);
    }
  }],
  data: {     
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Teal', 'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Black'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [123, 321, 213, 111, 222, 333, 234, 444],
      backgroundColor: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Teal', 'Yellow', 'Purple', 'Orange', 'Black']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    plugins: {
        datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'top'
      },
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          title: () => null
        }
      }
    },
      scales: {
          x: {
              title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'xAxis'
              }

          },
          y: {
                  display: false,
          },
          y1: {
              title: {
                  display: true,
                  text: 'yAxisLabel'
              },
              offset: true
          }
      }
  }, 
 
});
```

Output:

[image: Horizontal bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`formatter` function](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/formatting.html#data-transformation) to customize the displayed text for the data label.

In your case, you will show the `x` as the displayed data label.

```js
datalabels: {
  ...,
  formatter: function (value, context) {
    return value.x;
},
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1fvfjz?file=index.html)

[image]